# What is wrong with my html img src attribute code?

Tags: html

I am learning about image tag and attributes.

I tried something like the code down below, but in the opened HTML file, it only shows a small image (little rectangle image with one edge folded that you can sometimes see on websites).

```html
<img src="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=random%20image&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https://yt3.ggpht.com/-TPzt6V6JZIs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/otPdYjyxaNw/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg&t=h_" />
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, use only the url of the image. You don't need to add the duckduckgo.com link.

Try this:

```html
<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-TPzt6V6JZIs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/otPdYjyxaNw/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
```